# Add caption functionality to custom WordPress theme

Tags: functions, theme-development, the-content, single, captions

Hi I am working from a custom theme created by my predecessor and I am trying to add caption functionality to the theme but I am have some trouble with it.
Presently if I insert a image into a [post](http://www.hurford-salvi-carr.co.uk/blog/city-road-update-ec1?preview=true&preview_id=21048&preview_nonce=5cf55afefd)  and wish to add a caption, the caption would just appear next to the picture without any tags or classes containing it, here is a pic.

[image: screenshot]

I tried following another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850313/how-to-add-a-featured-image-caption-in-wordpress) and adding this piece of code to the function.php and to my single.php but nothing changed.

```
function the_post_thumbnail_caption() {
   global $post;

   $thumbnail_id    = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
   $thumbnail_image = get_posts(array('p' => $thumbnail_id, 'post_type' => 'attachment'));

  if ($thumbnail_image && isset($thumbnail_image[0])) {
     echo '<span>'.$thumbnail_image[0]->post_excerpt.'</span>';
  }
}

<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

What do I have to include to implement captions properly under my images?

Comment: You don't execute your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an image with caption to the WP text editor, it should add a [caption shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Caption_Shortcode). Is that the case here?

From there the output html should have some default classes like `wp-caption`.
You can then style your caption by applying some CSS to these classes:

```
/* The wrapper <div> for the caption and captioned element. */
.wp-caption { }

/* The caption text. */
.wp-caption-text { }

/* An image within the caption (you might want to style other elements too). */
.wp-caption img { }
```

See here: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/07/01/captions-in-wordpress

Alternatively you can customize the html output using the [caption shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/img_caption_shortcode) hook.

Comment: Yea I noticed the caption shortcode are there in the back-end however the styling does not exist. What classes do I have to include in style.css?

Comment: I found the problem, it was a plugin causing the issue

Comment: If the caption has the default css classes you can use them to style it. I updated my answer